# Why my react project server route not working when deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

Everything works fine when I work on localhost:8000 but when I deployed it to heroku all the routes are not working

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    cors = require("cors"),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8000,
    db = "beuter",
    path = require("path"),
    server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to on port ${port}`));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static('beuter/build'))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'beuter', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}

require("./server/config/database.config")(db);
require("./server/routes/product.route")(app);
```

and here is my `server/routes/product.route.js`:

```
const product = require("../controllers/product.controller");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.get("/api/products", product.index);

    // Create a product
    app.post("/api/products", product.create);

    // Get one product by title_url
    app.get("/api/products/:title_url", product.show_title_url)

    // Delete a product
    app.delete("/api/products/:id", product.deleteProduct)

    //Edit a product
    app.put("/api/products/:id", product.update)

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'beuter', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
};
```

This is the error in my chrome console

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/products' from origin 'https://thebeuter.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Here is the github project if you want to look over my code:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Updated:

Here is my Form.jsx from front-end:

```
  const addProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const product = {
      title,
      title_url,
      price,
      description1,
      description2,
      description3,
      description4,
      description5,
      img_url1,
      img_url2,
      img_url3,
      img_url4,
      size,
      size2,
      fit,
      fit2,
      category,
    };
    axios
      .post("https://localhost:8000/api/products", product)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          setErrors(res.data.errors);
        } else {
          navigate("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: Please add more details. Is there an issue when you do the deployment? Check the heroku logs, any errors there?

Comment: My deployment not having any error. I just seem like i cant get to routes in my backend server